# span tag not working after an ul

Tags: css, html-lists, html

I have a `ul` with a background image next to it. I have a text in a `span` tag which is not working and I can't figure out why.

This is The HTML code :

```
<div>
    <ul id="first" class="img_yellow_arrow" style="margin-left:120px">
      <span class="brightOrange"style="margin-left:5px">3&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="gris">nouveaux e-mails,</span>
       <li>A</li>
       <li>B</li>
       <li>C</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this my class :

```
.img_yellow_arrow{
content:url(images/yellow_arrow_2.png);
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

As I khow we can put an `<span>` inside an `<ul>` and I verified with the following code HTML :

```
<html>
<body>

<h4>An Unordered List:</h4>
<ul><span>x</span>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

</body>
```

I would greatly appreciate if you can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: That is invalid HTML, the only thing allowed within `<ul>` are `<li>` items

Comment: Is it true? Are only `<li>` items allowed in `<ul>`?

Comment: @Ranveer, yes... http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html  `Permitted contents: zero or more li elements`

Comment: Put `<span>` inside `<li>`

Comment: You are *replacing* the content of the `UL` with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css. Here is the code, http://jsfiddle.net/pTccG/

If you want to use background then, use background- image.

I think here in your code content overlay on the text.

```
instead of "content" use "background-image"..

    .img_yellow_arrow{
    background-image:url(images/yellow_arrow_2.png);
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue that it is invalid HTML in the first place

Comment: Thank you @JeevaJsb yes you are write finally the text was displayed but the image is not vertically aligned with the text!!

Comment: Thank you. You are not mentioned in the question about this requirement. But I couldn't get what you are saying . Are saying about image should be vertically aligned or Do you want to display Whole image and text also should be show ?

Comment: I want the image to be vertically aligned and the text also should be displayed

Comment: Sorry .. seriously i don't understand.. Do you want to rotate the image ? This is what vertically align as of now i found .. http://jsfiddle.net/pTccG/1/

Comment: Better you can go with the following website. It'll help you to learn basics. Thank you.. http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: Did you get answer ? Did I help you ?

Answer (score 2):

Change your HTML to:

```
<div><span class="brightOrange" style="margin-left:5px">3&nbsp;</span><span class="gris">nouveaux e-mails,</span>
    <ul id="first" class="img_yellow_arrow" style="margin-left:120px">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's currently invalid - `<span>` tags are not valid child elements of lists so should appear either outside the `<ul>` element, or within one of its child `<li>` elements.

See here for [further information from w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2)

Comment: Thank you for your response but I need the text to be displayed next to the ul tag

Comment: You'll need to style it appropriately so this happens then- can you provide a more detailed example of what you'd like?